# How to write unit tests for classes which use hardware resources?

Tags: java, testing, hardware

I created a class which extends from the [JSSC library](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector) and which uses low level communication methods (sendByte, sendString, etc.). I wanted to test it via JUnit, but I don't quite know how to do it.

For example, let's have a look at the method below:

```
public void openConnection() throws SerialPortException {
  serialPort.openPort();
  configureConnectionParameters(serialPort);
  configureReadListener(serialPort);
}
```

To ensure the method works properly, I need an actual hardware device to see if the port opens correctly and during the configuration process there were no Exceptions thrown. But playing with external resources during the unit testing is generally considered as a bad practice, so I started wondering if there are any solutions to such a problems (mocking up a hardware maybe?).

Or, do I have to unit test it at all?

Comment: There are mocking libraries for just this purpose.  http://jmockit.org is the one I use most at work; there's also Mockito, PowerMock.

Comment: You should consider first make an interface for SerialPort, ISerialPort, then mock it from your unit test program, finally use dependency injection to inject your mock into your class at testing time.

Comment: Thank you for your responses but either I don't understand mocking mechanism properly or I really can't use it here. `openConnection` uses `SerialPort` object inside itself so how am I supposed to mock it I can't modify tested method but only the sorrounding enviroment?

Comment: You will have to pass it in your class as a dependency. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably change the structure of your class and inject the `serialPort`.

This way you can mock out the injected serial port during your unit tests and additionally create a cleaner code with less hidden dependencies.

### Example:

```
public class PortHandler {

    private final SerialPort serialPort;

    public PortHandler(SerialPort serialPort) {
      this.serialPort = serialPort;
    }

    [...]

    public void openConnection() throws SerialPortException {
      serialPort.openPort();
      configureConnectionParameters(serialPort);
      configureReadListener(serialPort);
    }

    [...]
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void testShouldOpenPortOnOpenConnection()
      throws Exception {

    SerialPort mockedPort = mock(SerialPort.class);
    PortHandler portHandler = new PortHandler(mockedPort);
    portHandler.openConnection();

    verify(mockedPort, times(1)).openPort();
}
```

### Resources:

- Mocking framework used in example: [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)

Comment: I heard about DI but I alway thought it was highly specialized design principle for a larger apps. It comes that it is neither complicated nor as hard is I thought so. Great answer, thank you.